# Query-time don't show dupes from two fields

Tags: solr

A Solr index has two fields for which I do not want to show any dupes. I can prevent dupes from appearing on either one field or the other with grouping, however [Solr does not support grouping on multiple fields](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2526) currently. However, although one of the fields must be prevented from duping on an exact match, the other could prevent returning dupes on fuzzy (almost) matches. Note that these are very short fields, often on the order of one or two words.

Note that the dupes should remain in the index, I need only to prevent the dupes from showing in the results. I would simply filter them in the application but that would break pagination.

How can I prevent dupes (or even near dupes) on two fields in Solr 4?

Thank you.

**Example:**

No dupes on `First Name`, and no dupes on `Last Name`. These are the documents:

- First Name: John
- Last Name: Lennon
- Band: Beatles

- First Name: John
- Last Name: Jones
- Band: Led Zepplin

- First Name: Nick
- Last Name: Lennon
- Band: Independent

- First Name: Nick
- Last Name: Mason
- Band: Pink Floyd

First we'll return the first document:

- First Name: John
- Last Name: Lennon
- Band: Beatles

The second document will not be returned as it is a dupe on the `First Name` field.

The third document will not be returned as it is a dupe on the `Last Name` field.

The fourth document is not a dupe of of `First Name` or `Last Name` on any of the returned fields, so it is returned:

- First Name: Nick
- Last Name: Mason
- Band: Pink Floyd

We now have two documents.

Comment: Thank you Jayendra, I have added an example. I'm also reading your back posts to learn things. Thank you very much!

Comment: @dotancohen Could you introduce additional field with "First name" and "Last name" in it? After that you can prevent dupes from appearing on new field.

Comment: @Pavel: The names were just an example. The real data has a different idea about what is considered a dupe depending on the circumstances of the query, that is why I stress in the title that I am looking for a **query-time** solution. Thanks.